# Guava Maps.difference with wildcard

Tags: java, guava

I want to use Guava's `Maps.difference` in java 11 to verify data from Json String which I mapped into a Map.

What I have after a call (with different uid each time) :

```
{"uid":"31a340bc-e5ed-440c-8726-34c54dea902a","name":"Jean"}
```

I want to verify that uid is correctly generated and name is "Jean" using a pattern like this :

```
{"uid":"*","name":"Jean"}
```

Of course `Maps.difference` returns a difference in uid value...

Is it possible to specify a wildcard in my verifying pattern so that `Maps.difference` returns no differences ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Guava `Maps.difference`?

Comment: Why not just call Maps.difference, then call remove("uid") on the result?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean Guava's `Maps.difference`: yes, use the [`difference(left, right, valueEquivalence)` overload](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Equivalence-):

```
Maps.difference(left, right, new Equivalence<String>() {
  @Override public boolean doEquivalent(String a, String b) {
    return "*".equals(a) || "*".equals(b) || Objects.equals(a, b);
  }

  // You have to hash all strings to the same thing because you
  // don't know if the current item is a "*", or its corresponding
  // item is a "*". But actually it doesn't matter, because I don't
  // think it's invoked in difference.
  @Override public int doHash(String s) { return 0; }
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot !
Have a good day :)

Comment: @R.Del, please accept this answer if it solves your problem.